# TCPDF Adding Margin on Write Function

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Using the TCPDF Library, I am attempting to Center my Text with a right Margin.

So basically, take the whole width minus 0.25 inches and center the text based off of that. 
The TCPDF Library provides this documentation but does not provide information on how to set the margin on the `Write()` function.

```
Write( $h, $txt, $link = '', $fill = false, $align = '', $ln = false, $stretch = 0, $firstline = false, $firstblock = false, $maxh = 0, $wadj = 0, $margin = '' )
```

Here is my current code for writing the text:

```
$pdf->Write(4.5, 'Sample Text', '', false, 'C', false, 1, false, false, 0, 0, array(0, 0, 0.25, 0));
```

This is with myself assuming that Margin is an array (top, left, right, bottom).

So, how do I set the margins on the text in a `Write()` function while having the text centered still?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I set the margins on the text in a `Write()` function while having the text centered still?